# Is a double array an object?

Tags: java, arrays, object, double, int

We had a test yesterday and one of the multiple choice questions were:

How many objects would you have?

`double[] number = new double[6];`

`int number2 = 0;`

And I picked 2, there were no option for 0. Is this right? I have a feeling that this has nothing to do with objects.

Comment: the correct answer is 1. `double[]` is an object and even implements 2 interfaces: java.io.Serializable and java.lang.Cloneable. You can call the all inherited object methods: `equals, hashcode, wait, notify, notifyAll, toString`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is 1 object.  The array is regarded an object in itself.  The rest are all PDTs, i.e. doubles and ints.  There are 7 of them: 6 doubles in the array and 1 int the last declaration.

That's how we learn... :)

Comment: Great. She never talked about that. By that I mean objects in general. Ever

Comment: @AlexYan Objects were never brought up in a Java class? Can you transfer?

Comment: That's a bit of a trick question in my opinion.  If that definition was inside a class on the paper, you could argue that the second object is present as the class instance object, i.e. Blah.class.  Then you can get your mark!  If the question was on its own (like above), then I guess it won't be possible.

Comment: @Dave Nope. High school "CS" here sucks. A lot of our assignments were cut and paste and she doesn't do a very good job of explaining what all the objects were used for in all the methods

Comment: That's bad... my recommendation is that you try and learn the language yourself.  It's not hard... it just takes a bit of time.  Good luck!

Comment: Figured that before I took the course. I would be doing that if I didn't have any assignments from this class

Answer (score 1):

There will be only one object which will be the array.

Answer (score 1):

Only 1 object. Every array, no matter what it contains is ***an*** Object. And since your array contains only primitives (no Wrappers or objects) the array itself is the only object.

Comment: Changed "Every array, no matter what it contains is an array" to "Every array, no matter what it contains is an Object"